# Animating tikz pictures using beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I have two pictures drawn using TikZ. When I place them in two different frames in `beamer` they perfectly show up. But I want to animate them, that is, I want one picture after the other at a mouse click.

I have written this but I get only the first picture as the output.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
     \begin{animateinline}{2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
           .........
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \newframe*
     \begin{tikzpicture}
           .........
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{animateinline}  
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Do you want two TikZ pictures animated on *one* frame or each picture on each frame (then, there is no need for `animate`).